# Private fields/methods in Firefox - when will it be supported?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Does anyone know when Firefox will implement instance private fields and methods?

[image]

Chrome, Chromium, Edge... everyone else is there already...

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1435826 says it's fixed, https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields says it's not, the console says it's not... it's a mess...

Comment: *"Chrome, Chromium, Edge... everyone else is there already..."* Note that those all use the same JavaScript engine, V8. So that's one data point, not three. (Legacy Edge, the pre-Chromium version using Chakra, does not have either private methods or private fields.) Of the big three implementations, only V8 has them unflagged in the wild. JavaScriptCore and SpiderMonkey aren't *quite* there yet.

Comment: The big three implementations these days are: V8 (Node.js/Chromium/Chrome/etc.), JavaScriptCore (Safari, iOS Safari), and SpiderMonkey (Firefox). As I said above, V8 has both features unflagged in the wild. JavaScriptCore is getting close (the latest, v275655, has them unflagged but that isn't in the wild yet). The latest SpiderMonkey is v88.0b8, which still has them behind flags. So...probably soon.

Comment: (For completeness: Microsoft's Chakra engine doesn't have them. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/chakra-core/ChakraCore/issues/6136) to implement them in ChakraCore but no indication of progress or if it's even being worked on.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility), Firefox 90 already supports the whole range. Safari is lagging, though.
This is [fairly recent](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2021/06/implementing-private-fields-for-javascript/), and certainly not there when you asked this question.